# Is there a safe way to modify the table pg_constraint so as no more checking be done ( temporarily )?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

So as to restore a database from a dump, I want to temporarily disable all the constraints in all the tables of my database, which content I have emptied ( postregsql 8.3).

Is there a safe way to modify a field in the pg_constraint table that easily allows to bypass the constraint ?

I don't think so when I look at the documentation [pg_constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html).

Is it possible to drop the pg_constraint table content, then refill it again ?

If not, how people do restore/copy databases with tables that are full of constraints and foreign keys ? (my destination database has the schema but all the columns are empty).

**Edit:** althought Erwin Brandstetter's answer is the good answer (with wise warning) to my precise question... the solution to my general problem for avoiding foreign key errors during restore is to use the flag --disable-triggers when using pg_restore.

finally, my two lines commands are now:

```
pg_dump.exe  -h %ipAddress% -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -a -v -f %file% mydb
pg_restore.exe -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d mydb -v %file%  --disable-triggers
```

and it works ok.

Comment: `pg_restore` should automatically disable or defer foreign keys where it detects circular references in data-and-schema dumps; it does here with 9.1. I was pretty sure `pg_dump`'s SQL dumps did too. Can you explain what exactly is causing a problem with the restore? Are you having trouble with a `--data-only` dump? Did you use `--disable-triggers` with your `pg_dump` commandline? If you're using a `-Fc` format dump you can use `--disable-triggers` to `pg_restore` too.

Comment: i also posted about my general probleme here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23000/disable-constraints-before-using-pg-restore-exe and the solution given was to use --disable-triggers with pg_restore, and it works well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ...

```
ALTER TABLE tbl DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

This disables all *triggers* of the table permanently. So don't forget to later run:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

[-> 8.3 manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-altertable.html)

You can ...

```
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
```

This makes all deferrable constraints wait until the end of the *transaction*.
[-> 8.3 manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-set-constraints.html)

You should **never** tinker with tables in the system catalog manually unless you are a hacker and know exactly what you are doing. Mortal humans should use [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) commands exclusively to affect the system catalog.

Comment: If you know you want to do this when you run `pg_dump` in text mode, or if you are running `pg_restore`, you can use the `--disable-triggers` command-line option to accomplish this.

Comment: I never noticed `ALL`. Nice. I note it also has `DISABLE TRIGGER USER` for when you want to retain fk constraint triggers.

Answer (score 3):

If your constraints are `DEFERRABLE`, then you can do this:

```
SET CONSTRAINTS DEFERRED
```

However this just moves constraint checking on the next `COMMIT` - in other words its per transaction.

Generally for moving data, deploy some sort of [backup](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/backup.html) strategy.

Comment: +1 for the backup strategy, I think that's the proper way of doing that.