# how to export table backup without constraints in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

how to export table backup without constraints and triggers in Postgres

we are using below command

pg_dump -h hostname  -p 5432  -U postgres -d db  -t --disable-triggers table -v -f "table.backup"

but for skipping constraints do we have any option in postgres?

Comment: [Is there a safe way to modify the table pg_constraint so as no more checking be done ( temporarily )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093654/is-there-a-safe-way-to-modify-the-table-pg-constraint-so-as-no-more-checking-be)

Comment: i have disabled trigger but again trigger script is coming while taking pg_dump

Comment: I think you have to edit the output to delete (or comment) the lines that define the trigger?

Comment: if my output is in binary file how can i edit?

Comment: The definition of the trigger is part of the schema, therefore the answer to your question is that it is not possible to export table backup without the definitions of the trigger.

Comment: Is there any way to export tables structure with out  create structure of trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should dump the file, the `grep` statement will delete line containing "TRIGGER":

```
pg_dump -h hostname -p 5432 -U postgres -d db -t --disable-triggers --format=p table | grep -v TRIGGER > "table.backup"
```

P.S. Assumption is made that there is no word "TRIGGER" in the data of the table.

EDIT: On Windows this should work:

```
pg_dump -h hostname -p 5432 -U postgres -d db -t --disable-triggers --format=p table | FINDSTR /V TRIGGER > "table.backup"
```